# Acceder a elemento de pagina en otro dominio

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

En una página de mi sitio hice que un iframe me cargara una página que se encuentra en otro dominio, hasta ahí todo bien pero cuando quiero acceder a algun elemento de esa página me da error el Access-Control-Allow-Origin he investigado y la única manera de resolver el problema es añadir los permisos pero no puedo modificar la página alojada en el otro dominio.

Buscando otra vía me encontré que puedo usar la función file_get_contents y cargar la página de otro dominio dentro una página php de mi proyecto

```php
<?php
$url  = config('auth.CaptchaServerURL') . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$html = file_get_contents($url);

echo $html; 
?>
```

El problema es que las direcciones que apuntan los css y link son a mi dominio
ejemplo:
la página externa tiene

```
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Eso estaría bien si estoy viéndola desde su dominio pero una vez que la cargue en mi proyecto el va a buscar esa carpeta en mi proyecto.

Me podrían ayudar con este problema y gracias de antemano

Comment: El mensaje `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  es porque puede que solo permite recibir información del mismo dominio por lo cual si lo agregas a tu página no te permitirá visualizar o enviar información

Comment: No entiendo, buscas hacer como un scraping de la otra página ?

Comment: si exacto, quiero obtener un input hidden que se encuentra en la pagina externa

Comment: El mensaje de "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" es por temas de seguridad, es para evitar cross-site scripting ( https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) ya que el iframe justamente se encuentra en otro dominio. Si lo que quieres es scrappear, te recomiendo que uses alguna libreria pensada para ese fin.